# Chipset Information - AMD OR Intel

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to get the chipset off multiple servers. Just testing the main line that will get this information.

Some servers have Intel and others have AMD - when I use the below it really does not work - it just sends everything back - I will choose `First 1` so I only get back one but how do I make sure the script looks at either Intel or AMD only?

```
Get-WMIObject win32_pnpentity -ComputerName SERVERNAME| where { $_.caption -like "*AMD*" -or "*Intel*" } | select caption #-First 1
```

Output I get:

```
caption                                                                                                                                      
-------                                                                                                                                      
ACPI Multiprocessor PC                                                                                                                       
Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System                                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz                                                                                              
PCI bus                                                                                                                                      
Intel(R) 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port - 3406                                                                                            
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 - 3408                                                                           
Smart Array P410i Controller                                                                                                                 
HP Virtual LUN                                                                                                                               
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device                                                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 2 - 3409                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 - 340A                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 4 - 340B                                                                                
Intel(R) 7500/5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 5 - 340C                                                                                
Intel(R) 7500/5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 6 - 340D                                                                                
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 - 340E                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 8 - 340F                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 9 - 3410                                                                           
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 10 - 3411                                                                          
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500/X58 Physical Layer Port 0 - 3418                                                                                     
Intel(R) 7500/5520/5500 Physical Layer Port 1 - 3419                                                                                         
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard host CPU bridge                                                                                                                 
PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge                                                                                                               
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE #62                                                                                                      
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) #62                                                                                    
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE #63                                                                                                      
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) #63                                                                                    
PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge                                                                                                               
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE #103                                                                                                     
Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client) #103                                                                                   
Standard Universal PCI to USB Host Controller                                                                                                
USB Root Hub
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out - it should be:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_pnpentity -ComputerName SERVERNAME | where {( $_.caption -like "*AMD*" ) -or ($_.caption -like "*Intel*")} | select caption -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Win32_BaseBoard` and `Win32_Bios` WMI classes.